# How can I use two records from the same Rails model as foreign keys in a different Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have two models: person.rb and relationship.rb

I need my :relationships table to reference two rows from the :people table as foreign keys.

Here are the migrations for both tables:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :second_name
      t.integer :age
      t.string :gender
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.references :person_a
      t.references :person_b
      t.string :status
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is the :person_a and :person_b fields will both be individual records from the :people table referenced as foreign keys, while the :status field will just be a description of their relationship ("Married", "Friends", "Separated", etc.)

I'm trying to find out:

1) What is the additional code I have to write in the CreateRelationships migration above in order to set :person_a and :person_b up as foreign keys from the :people table?

2) What code do I need to write in the model files (person.rb and relationship.rb) for both tables below to define the relationship structure I'm talking about?

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I've found one other question on here that deals with this issue, but the answers given were conflicting, some incomplete, and others working with older versions of Rails. None of them have worked for me.

I'm using Rails 5.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Apologies for a rushed and wrong answer.

Initially, I thought that simple `has_many/belongs_to` association is possible and sufficient.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships #dependent: :destroy
end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person_a, class_name: "Person"
  belongs_to :person_b, class_name: "Person"

  enum status: [:married, :friends, :separated]
end
```

As @engineersmnky pointed out, `has_many` association can't work here because there is no `person_id` column in `relationships` table. Since we can declare only one custom foreign key in `has_many` association, it's not possible to declare it here this way. `belongs_to` will work, but I don't think that's enough.

One way is to skip declaring `has_many` and stick to custom method for querying relationships:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  def relationships
    Relationship.where("person_a_id = ? OR person_b_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

It will give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation` to work with, containing exactly the records you need. The drawbacks of this solution are numerous - depending on your needs, you will probably need more code for inserting data, starting with a setter method to assign relationships to people...

What could be a real solution, is to have a composite primary key in Relationship model - composed of `:person_a_id` and `:person_b_id`. ActiveRecord doesn't support composite primary keys, but [this gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) seems to fill the gap. Apparently it allows to declare such key and use it as a foreign key in a `has_many` association. The catch is that your person_a/person_b pairs would have to be unique across `relationships` table.

Comment: And how exactly do you expect `Person#relationships` to function in this case? The query generated will be `SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE person_id = X` but person_id is not part of the relationships table

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for pointing that out, my facepalm was crisp and loud. Answer edited.

Comment: @BartoszPietraszko  I've still got your original solution implemented and it seems to work in that it forms the associations and allows me to retrieve/display all of the relationships complete with data about the people in them in my relationships#index and relationships#show actions/views. I'm a bit new to Rails and don't really understand what the problem with that solution was or the stuff you describe as being the better solution. Do you think it would be okay if I just stuck with the first solution as long as it seems to do what I need? Or will there be problems later on?

Comment: It only works in one direction. Try displaying a person in PeopleController if you have one, and you'll get error when you get to @person.relationships . If you don't need it to work both ways, then stick to the code that you have - but delete has_many association from Person model, because it won't work.

Comment: In case you need to load @person.relationships: if you are a newcomer to rails and your app isn't mission-critical, you will be probably better off writing custom methods as I described. Composite primary keys are pretty non-standard stuff, and you'll learn more working around the problem manually :) thanks for posting a challenging question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer it :)

Answer (score 3):

You have defined you migration correctly just add the following in your model to define the relationship between the model.

```
    class Person < ApplicationRecord::Base
      has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
    end

    class Relationship < ApplicationRecord::Base
      belongs_to :person_a, :class_name => 'Person'
      belongs_to :person_b, :class_name => 'Person'
    end
```

This allows you to access the Person that a Relationship belongs to like this:

```
@relationship.person_a #user assigned as the first person.
@relationship.person_b #user assigned as the second person.
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Himanshu do you think I'd be better off switching from this to the updated solution described by Bartosz below?  He and another user have noticed a problem with this solution.  I'm still using this solution and it seems to be working, but I don't know if it's safe for me to continue using it or if I might run into a problem later on because of the issue they describe.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same for a chat module, this is an example to how you can do it:

```
class Conversations < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :senders, through: :conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recipients, through: :conversations, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

More explanations at [complex-has-many-through](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/complex-has-many-through/)

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
In relationship model write

```
belongs_to : xyz, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "person_a"
belongs_to : abc, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "person_b"
```

In Person model write

```
has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
```

hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Can I ask what "xyz" and "abc" are supposed to represent?  The answers from Himanshu and Bartosz place :person_a/:person_b after the "belongs_to" tags, whereas you've put those values (or string versions of them) in a "foreign_key" tag instead. What are those things you're putting in "belongs_to" ?

Comment: You can replace "xyz" and "abc" by name through which you want to access associated record. Let's say replace "xyz" to "sender" then you can access person like  (Relationship.first.sender  where you have foreign key person_a_id in relationships table.)